# Classes and functions parameter using problem in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I just wrote a function to search the binary tree for the closest number in tree. This is what I wrote below. However, it seems that the self.res in the dfs function does not renew the self.res in closeestValue function. I know I can write the dfs into the closestValue to solve the problem. But I do want to write two seperated functions. Is there any solution for that? Thank you!

```
class Solution:
    """
    @param root: the given BST
    @param target: the given target
    @return: the value in the BST that is closest to the target
    """
    def closestValue(self, root, target):
        # write your code here
        if root is None:
            return None

        self.res = root.val
        self.dfs(root, target)
        return self.res



    def dfs(self, aroot, atarget):
        if not aroot:
            return None

        if abs(aroot - atarget) < abs(self.res - atarget):
            self.res = aroot.val
        if atarget > aroot.val:
            self.dfs(aroot.right, atarget)
        else:
            self.dfs(aroot.left, atarget)
        return aroot.val
```

Comment: I mean self.res in closestValue is not loaded into dfs. My mistake

Comment: Well, there seems to be some conflict between doing `self.res = <value>` versus `return <value>`...

Comment: Try to mentally (or on paper-and-pencil...) trace your `dfs` function: see where that gets you.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The call of res is not a problem. The abs(aroot - atarget) should be abs(aroot.val - atarget).